# Replaced left crank arm but still comes loose?

Tags: repair, crankset, bottom-bracket, damage

A few weeks ago I bought a new (albeit cheap) self assembly bike from a local store, this bike to be exact http://tinyurl.com/gw77p9t . After about two weeks use (one and a half hours of cycling on pavement five days a week) the left crank started to creak, came loose and eventually fell off. I cleaned the crank and applied new grease which stopped the creaking and prevented it from falling off but the crank still came loose so as to make cycling uncomfortable. I then bought a new crank arm (this crank arm http://tinyurl.com/zz3mjzr ), took off the old crank, cleaned and greased again only to find the same problem. I can't imagine what else the problem could be, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you tighten the crank enough? If you don't have a torque wrench, the correct torque is really tight. If it doesn't feel like something is about to give, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I tightened it as much as physically possible without breaking my arm.

Comment: It sounds like you need a longer wrench.

Comment: Would that be a problem? The handle on the wrench I'm using is about 15-20 cm long (I'm trying to estimate from memory).

Comment: Too short wrench. You need something about 40cm length, and yet you need much power to tighten it well. And as Batman answered, you probably damaged the BB spindle.

Comment: So I need to buy a torque wrench and a new BB? Yikes, so much for buying a cheap bike.

Comment: You need about 35 to 40 N-m to tighten a crank typically. That's probably more than you think you need. I'd let the shop do the whole thing, since you'll probably use them to do the BB anyway.

Comment: I'd prefer to do any maintenance myself (for the purposes of learning), I might be able to borrow the appropriate tools off of a friend. Is this a good idea, or is there a high chance of damaging the bike further if I attempt to do this?

Comment: There are good instructions on how to do the replacement on parktool.com , so provided you can follow them and have access to the right tools, you can do it yourself. But given how often this repair needs to be done, I don't think its a particularly valuable skill to have. In some cases when things get stuck though, you will want a properly stocked shop (so you have a real repair stand rather than a portable repair stand, and a longer breaker bar than most home people will have access to).

Comment: I guess the worst thing you can do is ruin the threads in the bottom bracket, in which case you'd probably use a universal BB (e.g. the velo orange). Using Torque = Force x Arm, you can figure out roughly how much 35-40 Nm feels like, if you don't use a torque wrench. I'd suggest using a wrench in the 2 foot range. You can also look up the appropriate torques in the documentation for the bike.

Comment: I have access to this tool kit http://tinyurl.com/hyskqhg . The only tool which seems to fit around the hexagonal bolt which keeps coming loose is this http://imgur.com/Hf7QK5R , but it provides no leverage for tightening to the recommended 35-40Nm, does this tool have a different function to what I think or perhaps it connects to some other item in the tool box to make a lever?

Comment: I ended up using the peddle wrench to turn the hexagonal head of the thread extractor around the bolt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loose crank arm can damage both the bottom bracket and the crank arms. In your case, since you've run the crank arm til it fell off the bike, it is likely you ruined the bottom bracket. If your crank arm is loose, immediately stop and tighten it.

You will need to likely get a new bottom bracket and possibly yet another new crank arm. Replacing a bottom bracket requires a special tool (bottom bracket tool) and a compatible bottom bracket (which will typically be marked on the bottom bracket itself). You may want to leave this job to a bike shop.

Comment: If you replace the BB, consider to take a cheap sealed bearings. It will not cost much more, but will last much longer.

Comment: What are sealed bearings and what is their function (this is my first bike and I'm still learning)?

Comment: Its basically the modern bottom bracket. If you go to a bike shop, its what they'll install. Cheaper bikes use an older style.